How to highlight multi-line comment block TODOs with VSCode Highlight extension
I did not find many stuff on that matter around here and managed to cook a satisfying result that I want to share.
I am using VSCode Highlight extension, which uses regexes to match and highlight TODOs, FIXMEs, or anything you want in your code.
The author provides example regexes for generic languages, here is what the settings.json file looks like:
"highlight.regexFlags": "gi",
"highlight.regexes": {
  "((?:<!-- *)?(?:#|// @|//|./\\*+|<!--|--|\\* @|{!|{{!--|{{!) *TODO(?:\\s*\\([^)]+\\))?:?)((?!\\w)(?: *-->| *\\*/| *!}| *--}}| *}}|(?= *(?:[^:]//|/\\*+|<!--|@|--|{!|{{!--|{{!))|(?: +[^\\n@]*?)(?= *(?:[^:]//|/\\*+|<!--|@|--(?!>)|{!|{{!--|{{!))|(?: +[^@\\n]+)?))": {
    "filterFileRegex": ".*(?<!CHANGELOG.md)$",
    "decorations": [
      {
        "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffcc00",
        "color": "#1f1f1f",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#ffcc00",
        "color": "#1f1f1f"
      }
    ]
  },
  { ... }
}

But being language-agnostic, the regexes are getting quite complex and difficult to edit, and more importantly I want my todo notes to be matched on multiple lines, here in python for example:
# TODO (example): only this line is highlighted :( the rest of my
# extensive note on multiple lines
# is not matched.
def my_code(something):
    does_something()

How to match multiple lines ?

So this is the solution I came up with, that I posted as an answer here before thinking it would maybe deserve a dedicated post.
First, the extension provides "filterLanguageRegex" to limit search pattern to specific languages. So that you can have one pattern using // Comment and /* Comment */, another for # Comment, etc.
Then, this is what the regex looks like to match the python example TODO note on multiple lines:
"highlight.regexFlags": "gi",
"highlight.regexes": {
    "(#+ *TODO(?:\\s*\\([^)]+\\))?:?)(.*(?:\\n[ \\t]*#+.+)*)": {
        "filterLanguageRegex": "python|ruby|perl|bash",
        "filterFileRegex": ".*(?<!CHANGELOG.md)$",
        "decorations": [
            {
                "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffff0066",
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "fontWeight": "bold"
            },
            {
                "backgroundColor": "#ffff0066",
                "color": "#ffffff",
            }
        ]
    },
}

Note: "backgroundColor": "#ffff0066" uses a color hexcode with a low alpha value so that highlighted text under selection can still be differentiated from the rest of the highlighted line.
With this regex:
# TODO (example): this note is highlighted
# on multiple lines
# up to this line.
#
# This part of the comment is no more highlighted
def my_code(something):
    does_something() ### TODO this is highlighted too.

You can then define a new regex with slashes for javascript, c++ etc. languages, another one for html, etc.
